# How do I commit a transaction when using JdbcRepository?

Tags: micronaut

I have two `@JdbcRepository` annotated repositories, which represent two Postgresql schemas.   Each schema is in a separate datasource, which means each Repository has its own transaction manager.  In the SQL table definitions, one table has a foreign key constraint on the other.  The two repos look like:

```java
@Repository("schema1")
@JdbcRepository
public abstract class RepoTypeA implements PageableRepository<TypeA, Long> {
  // ...
}
```

```java
@Repository("schema2")
@JdbcRepository
public abstract class RepoTypeB implements PageableRepository<TypeB, Long> {
  // ...
}
```

The Postgres SQL definitions look like:

```sql
create table if not exists schema1.typea_table (
    typea_id            bigserial primary key,
    typeb_id            bigint not null ,

    CONSTRAINT typeb_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (typeb_id)
        REFERENCES schema2.typeb_table (typeb_id),
);

create table if not exists schema2.typeb_table (
    typeb_id            bigserial primary key,
);
```

And finally the datatypes in Java look like:

```java
@Introspected
@MappedEntity("typea_table")
public class TypeA {
  @Id @GeneratedValue Long typea_id;
  @NonNull Long typeb_id;
}
```

```java
@Introspected
@MappedEntity("typeb_table")
public class TypeB {
  @Id @GeneratedValue Long typeb_id;
}
```

The problem is that trying to use `RepoTypeA` and `RepoTypeB` together breaks when creating the two objects.   Creating a TypeB and then using its typeb_id in TypeA fails the foreign key constraint, since the TypeB record hasn't been committed yet.   There doesn't appear to be a way to make both changes in the same transaction.   Both repos have their own transaction manager, with names like `schema1` and `schema2`, and it would be infeasible to change them, as other parts of the program depend on them.

Another approach which doesn't work is using the `SynchronousTransactionManager<Connection>`.   The transaction manager expects to call a callback with the connection, but since the RepoTypeA and RepoTypeB classes have their JDBI objects injected for them, there is no way to pass in the transaction.   Example:

```java
// This does NOT work
@Inject @Named("schema2") 
SynchronousTransactionManager<Connection> txManager;

{ 
  txManager.executeWrite(
            status -> {
              return repoTypeB.save(new TypeB());
            });
}
```

I'm looking for a way to either force both object repositories to use the same transaction, or, force creation of TypeB by committing the transaction, blocking, and then starting a transaction on TypeA.

Comment: "Creating a TypeB and then using its typeb_id in TypeA fails the foreign key constraint, since the TypeB record hasn't been committed yet." - Why is it that you can't commit the transaction?

Comment: Separate question, what are the isolation levels set to for the 2 transactions?

Comment: The transaction can't be committed because there is no public method to commit it, and no transaction object on which to call the method.   The TypeB object may not exist at the beginning of the top level HTTP call.   Currently we use SERIALIZABLE transactions, which means if any part of our code accidentally creates a TX, it would violate the serializable isolation level.  Hence, what I am looking for is how to take manual control of the transactions, and have it not be automatically managed.  The challenge is that PageableRepository does not play well with manual TX management.

Comment: One other observation: DataSourceTransactionManager refuses to commit the TX at the end of the call, if it wasn't the one that started the TX in the first place.

Comment: We have some transactions handling improvements in Micronaut Data 3.4.0 maybe try if there is something different. The injection of different tx managers should work. Anyway, I don’t think it’s a good idea to separate schema objects into datasources, in that case you use two transactions and that is not going to lead to always consistent rollbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one datasource and two schemas. Looks like the mapped entity annotation doesn’t support schemas but you can use JPA’s Entity annotation as a workaround.